# Handling time in C++

Tags: c++, time, sfml

I am writing a simulation program. I have some difficulties when handling the time.

My program has a time period and a total elapsed time variables. I have traffic light objects. I want to change the color of them when the elapsed time is integer multiple of the period. For example, say total time starts from 0 and finishes in 60 seconds and the period is 10 seconds. So, when time is 10, 20, 30, etc. , the color should be changed.

I tried solving this issue with using simple math but nothing has been changed when I draw the objects. So, how can I handle the time to change their colors?

Comment: Have a look at: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono

Comment: @drescherjm I forgot to mension it. I am using SFML library.

Comment: I assume then you have an event loop. If so then your update each object (traffic light) should handle this internally.

Comment: @RichardCritten Yes, I have an event loop. Actually, I tried these operations in update part, but I cannot handle the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the standard `<chrono>` library, but SFML has its own set of tools for handling time. You don't need any complicated calculations or threads. A simplified example of part of what you need:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <vector>

class Light : public sf::CircleShape {
public:
    Light(std::vector<sf::Color> cols, sf::Time period) 
        :colors{ cols }, colorIdx{ 0 }, changePeriod{ period }
    {
        setRadius(100);
    }

    void update(sf::Time deltaTime) {
        elapsedTime += deltaTime;
        while (elapsedTime >= changePeriod) {
            elapsedTime -= changePeriod;
            changeColor();
        }
        setColor();
    }
protected:
    void changeColor() {
        if (++colorIdx == colors.size()) {
            colorIdx = 0;
        }
    }

    void setColor() {
        setFillColor(colors[colorIdx]);
    }
private:
    std::vector<sf::Color> colors;
    std::size_t colorIdx;
    sf::Time changePeriod;
    sf::Time elapsedTime;
};

int main() {
    Light light1({sf::Color::Red, sf::Color::Yellow, sf::Color::Green}, sf::seconds(1));

    Light light2({sf::Color::Red, sf::Color::Green}, sf::milliseconds(200));
    light2.setPosition(300, 300);
    light2.setRadius(20);

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(400, 400), "");
    sf::Event event;
    sf::Clock clock;

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) window.close();
        }

        sf::Time dt = clock.restart();
        light1.update(dt);
        light2.update(dt);

        window.clear();
        window.draw(light1);
        window.draw(light2);
        window.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Dessus, I tried it and it works. When I start the application, it starts with full black screen. After 5 to 10 seconds, my simulator works.

Comment: It's quite a long time.

Comment: Yes. In some parts of the program, my implementation is not good enough. Also, if my program works about 30 seconds, then it gives a segmentation fault (core dumped) error.

Comment: Maybe I should fix these parts and find the reason why it gives me a segmentation fault.

Answer (score -2):

You could use `delay(milliseconds)` with the header file `#include<dos.h>`. For example if you want your traffic lights to be changed every 10 seconds in 60 seconds you could do the following code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i ++)
{
   changeColor();
   delay(1000);
}
```

Also, you could use `sleep()`. You may find the answer to your question here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/13906/

Comment: I use Ubuntu, therefore I cannot include dos.h into my program. Is there a header file for Linux OS?

Comment: Check whether this header file works or not? #include<unistd.h> for sleep

Comment: Yes, this header file works in my OS. Thanks. I will try it in a minute.

Comment: If your compiler was made in the last ten years-or-so you can use [`std::this_thread::sleep_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) and your program will not be bound to a particular operating system. Try to avoid stuff like dos.h. dos.h supports the DOS operating system, Microsoft's flagship OS from the 1980s. It's been a while since DOS was relevant. Using it is kind of like going shopping with a flint-tipped spear.

Comment: That said, learn to use the event loop for this. It'll keep your GUI from freezing up.